# Python Numpy FFT

Tags: python, list, numpy, fft

Have a question about the capability of numpy fft.  If I have two lists one with time and one with values corresponding to those times is it possible to use the numpy fft on that Data?

Comment: Yes. You will be able to find examples here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft

Comment: Have you done any research, read the NumPy docs?